# How do I create a loop for this VBA macro?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, dry

I have a training matrix, and I want to be able to click on each person's name, and it copies their row into a report style format on a separate sheet.

I found something that works, but since I am not a programmer at all, I have been copying and pasting the same lines of code for each row in the excel table... I realize there is a much better way to do this, but I don't know how. I figured I could just get away with it until I ran into the "procedure too large" error.

Currently, I set each persons name as a link to a cell in the document (A1), and then I have this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If Target.Range.Address = "$A$4" Then
       Sheets("Report").Activate
       Sheets("Data Table").Range("A4:E4").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Report").Range("B2")
       Sheets("Data Table").Range("F3:BAA3").Copy
       Sheets("Report").Range("A4").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True, Paste:=xlPasteValues
       Sheets("Data Table").Range("F1:BAA1").Copy
       Sheets("Report").Range("B4").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True, Paste:=xlPasteValues
       Sheets("Data Table").Range("F2:BAA2").Copy
       Sheets("Report").Range("C4").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True, Paste:=xlPasteValues
       Sheets("Data Table").Range("F4:BAA4").Copy
       Sheets("Report").Range("D4").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True, Paste:=xlPasteValues
       Sheets("Report").Range("D4:D1500").Select
       Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    If Target.Range.Address = "$A$5" Then
       Sheets("Report").Activate
       Sheets("Data Table").Range("A5:E5").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Report").Range("B2")
       Sheets("Data Table").Range("F1:BAA1").Copy
       Sheets("Report").Range("B4").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True, Paste:=xlPasteValues
       Sheets("Data Table").Range("F3:BAA3").Copy
       Sheets("Report").Range("A4").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True, Paste:=xlPasteValues
       Sheets("Data Table").Range("F2:BAA2").Copy
       Sheets("Report").Range("C4").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True, Paste:=xlPasteValues
       Sheets("Data Table").Range("F5:BAA5").Copy
       Sheets("Report").Range("D4").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True, Paste:=xlPasteValues
       Sheets("Report").Range("D4:D1500").Select
       Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

You'll notice the only changes in each block are the "If" range and the first and fourth data table ranges, going up by one each time. I have 212 rows total, and will add more in the future.

I would like something that does the same thing only much more efficiently (like a LOOP) and hopefully without the need to modify when adding another person! I have a feeling this is very possible and not as hard as I am imagining, but as I said, I am definitely not a programmer.

Any help following the DRY philosophy would be greatly appreciated!!! =)

-David

TLDR: I tried putting in 212 of these if statements and it stopped working at about 70 entries, procedure is too large. I figured I would ask here how I can write a loop before I tried on my own to split it up into 3 similar procedures...

Comment: Assign the target range to a variable then use that as a starting point. It's a good idea to [avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim rw As Range, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set rw = Target.EntireRow 'the row with the clicked link
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
    
    CopyValues rw.Range("A1:E1"), ws.Range("B2") 'Note: `Range` is *relative* to `rw`
                                                 '  and not to the sheet
    ' `Me` is the worksheet for this code module...
    CopyValues Me.Range("F1:BAA1"), ws.Range("B4"), True 'True=Transpose
    CopyValues Me.Range("F2:BAA2"), ws.Range("C4"), True
    CopyValues Me.Range("F3:BAA3"), ws.Range("A4"), True
    
    CopyValues rw.Range("F1:BAA1"), ws.Range("D4"), True
    
    ws.Range("D4:D1500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    
End Sub

'copy values between `rngSrc` and `rngDest`, with optional Transpose (defaults to False)
'  Note: Transpose has an upper limit of about 65k cells....
Sub CopyValues(rngSrc As Range, rngDest As Range, Optional Transpose As Boolean = False)
    With rngSrc
        If Transpose Then
            rngDest.Cells(1).Resize(.Columns.Count, .Rows.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.Value)
        Else
            rngDest.Cells(1).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I dont have much time right now to look this over but I saw your note about transpose limit of 65k cells, I have 200ish employees (rows) and 1100 procedures (columns).I do grab our SOP count x4 (number, name, revision letter, matching employee training data) so 4000 cells max, then possibly a few hundred new SOP's, so I think the maximum number of cells I would ever be trying to transpose is 5000.

Comment: Limit is only *per call* and (eg) F:BAA is 1374 columns, so I think there's no issue there...

Comment: Made a few edits above: `rw.Range(...)` to  `Me.Range(...)`

Answer (score 0):

If target is in column A and row number between 4 to 100 (update as needed), copy/pasting will be executed.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim c As Range
    Set c = Target.Range
    If c.Column = 1 And (c.Row >= 4 And c.Row <= 100) Then
       Sheets("Report").Activate
       Sheets("Data Table").Range("A" & c.Row).Resize(1, 5).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Report").Range("B2")
       Sheets("Data Table").Range("F3:BAA3").Copy
       Sheets("Report").Range("A4").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True, Paste:=xlPasteValues
       Sheets("Data Table").Range("F1:BAA1").Copy
       Sheets("Report").Range("B4").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True, Paste:=xlPasteValues
       Sheets("Data Table").Range("F2:BAA2").Copy
       Sheets("Report").Range("C4").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True, Paste:=xlPasteValues       
       Sheets("Data Table").Range("F" & c.Row).Resize(1, 1374).Copy 
       Sheets("Report").Range("D4").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True, Paste:=xlPasteValues
       Sheets("Report").Range("D4:D1500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet FollowHyperlink: Copy Values To Another Sheet

[image]

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1(Data Table)`**

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    
    'Debug.Print Target.Range.Address
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = Me ' Data Table
    'Set sws = Target.Range.Worksheet
    
    ' Reference the target range in the source worksheet.
    Dim trg As Range:
    Set trg = sws.Range("A4", sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    
    ' Attempt to reference the target cell.
    Dim tCell As Range: Set tCell = Intersect(trg, Target.Range)
    If tCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no intersection (no target cell)
    
    ' Reference the destination worksheet.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = sws.Parent.Sheets("Report")
    'Set dws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report")
    'Set dws = Target.Range.Worksheet.Parent.Sheets("Report")
    
    ' Declare variables.
    Dim srg As Range, drg As Range
    
    ' Copy 'A:E'
    Set srg = tCell.EntireRow.Columns("A:E")
    Set drg = dws.Range("B2")
    srg.Copy drg
    
    ' Copy 'F:BAA'
    Set srg = sws.Columns("F:BAA")
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = srg.Columns.Count
    Set drg = dws.Range("A4:D4").Resize(cCount)
    With Application
        drg.Columns(1).Value = .Transpose(srg.Rows(3).Value)
        drg.Columns(2).Value = .Transpose(srg.Rows(1).Value)
        drg.Columns(3).Value = .Transpose(srg.Rows(2).Value)
        drg.Columns(4).Value = .Transpose(srg.Rows(tCell.Row).Value)
    End With
    
    ' Attempt to reference the empty cells in destination column 'D'.
    Set drg = Nothing ' reset
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if no empty cells
        Set drg = dws.Range("D4", dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)) _
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Delete entire rows of the empty cells.
    If Not drg Is Nothing Then ' there are empty cells
        drg.EntireRow.Delete
    'Else ' no empty cells; do nothing
    End If

End Sub
```